# Linux electron npm give me install-app-deps: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make my electron app work on linux. It's working fine on Windows.
When I'm trying a 'npm ci', I get the following error :

`sh: 1: install-app-deps: not found`

I haven't found anything usefull on google. I guess it could be my electron-forge who can be this trouble source, but I don't know any turn around for it.

My Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "roseplayer",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "A webradio player",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "run": "electron .",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "Khan From Chedum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "node-internet-radio": "^0.2.1",
    "radio-browser": "^2.1.7",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "electron": "^12.0.10"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "./img/outline_filter_vintage_black_48dp.ico"
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "roseplayer"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My github : [link](https://github.com/KhanFromChedum/RosePlayer)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake:

I'm using electron-forge and therefore I can't use npm install nor npm ci.

For more information, in case you're interested, you can go to the electron-forge home page.